# Open HTML file in C# application

Tags: c#, html, visual-studio-2010

I have added an HTML file to my solution in VS2010. How do you create a call to open the HTML file? For example when a user clicks a button it will locate the HTML file in my solution and open it in the web browser.

Comment: Looks like System.Diagnostics.Process.Start is the right command from c#

Comment: what are you using c# console app/ asp.net form/asp.net mvc ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**you can use web browser control**

```
webbrowser.Navigate("File location.html")
```

for more information see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7194851/load-local-html-file-in-a-c-sharp-webbrowser)

Comment: To: Gerard Sexton
if i give the application to run on someone else machine it it confuse the path i stated on my machine with there's?

Comment: use this "Application.StartupPath" for getting your appication startup path

Answer (score 0):

```
System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(
  Server.MapPath("~/HtmlFileFolderNameInSolution/") + "HtmlFileName.htm"
);
```

This will open HTML file in new tab of same browser...

Comment: what name space do i have to add when i am adding this in? everything works till Server.MapPath. does it fall under the System.Web;??