# WPF doesn't let local HTML file access an object in my disk

Tags: c#, html, wpf, local

I use a `Marmoset viewer .mview` file and a `html` file from my local disk that should load it. I plan to make appear the 3D scene in my wpf browser. 
The browser itself works, can display marmoset scenes found online, but cannot retrieve the *.mview* package. I tried [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7194851/load-local-html-file-in-a-c-sharp-webbrowser) here as well but to no avail: the html file loads but can't access my other file (they are in the same folder as needed).

How can I allow a html file to get access to my local disk to load that file? (All that marmoset needs to show the scene is to have the .mview file in the same folder as the html file that loads it. Everything else is done by a script that comes with the export).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason this didn't work was that WPF integrated browsers (default IE, gecko or cefsharp) regards accessing your hdd a security risk for software so they block this opportunity.

To get around this, Marmoset suggests a local http server named "mongoose".

Furthermore, marmoset exported viewer files work by running a JavaScript file they access via the internet by default. To make your wpf projects both more robust and secure, download that JS file and add to your project.

That way I could fully integrate a marmoset realtime viewer inside any WPF container (I had a window, in it a user control, in it a grid. the page was shown in the grid).