# Print an HTML page in C#

Tags: c#

On click of a button, I am trying to print the HTML page

[image]

I think the problem is in the path? Without hardcoding how should I print this document, currently it just opens the printer tray and prints `This page cant be displayed`.

help.html

```
<html>
<head>
<body>
This is my testing...
<body>
</head>
</html>
```

Here is my C# code

```
   private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            // Create a WebBrowser instance. 
            WebBrowser webBrowserForPrinting = new WebBrowser();

            // Add an event handler that prints the document after it loads.
            webBrowserForPrinting.DocumentCompleted +=
                new WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventHandler(PrintDocument);

            // Set the Url property to load the document.
            webBrowserForPrinting.Url = new Uri(@"D:\PMO Project\PMO\WindowsFormsApplication1\WindowsFormsApplication1\HTML\help.html");
        }

        private void PrintDocument(object sender,
            WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventArgs e)
        {
            // Print the document now that it is fully loaded.
            ((WebBrowser)sender).Print();

            // Dispose the WebBrowser now that the task is complete. 
            ((WebBrowser)sender).Dispose();
        }
```

Screenshot of what is printed

[image]

Comment: Can you show us a screenshot of the "printer tray"? Or do you mean that the physical paper try on the physical printer is popping out?

Comment: @EdPlunkett I just checked the printer prints the page but its not the html page that it is printing (doenst print help.html) but it prints the page cant be displayed res://ieframe.dll/dnserrordiaoff.htm

Comment: Is your help.html valid? Did you try to open it in browser?

Comment: @MegaTron question updated with html

Comment: try attaching your webbrowser control to the form (you have a window application with one or more form, ain't it?), and check you can load the html. Possibly you are even loading your page, meaning the problem is before the printing

Comment: I like the hardcoded path to your project directory. It's the little details like that -- or posting a question about why it's not printing without first walking over to the printer to see if any paper came out -- which really bring a question to life. But never mind me, I'm a cruel and whimsical old man. I suggest you *temporarily* put a WebBrowser control in your UI where you can see it, and figure out how to compile the HTML file *as a resource* and load it in the WebBrowswer. Once you can see it on the screen, then work on printing it. Then you'll be able to make this work.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7194851/load-local-html-file-in-a-c-sharp-webbrowser