# Load html file in a C# WebBrowser component

Tags: c#, wpf, file, webbrowser-control

In my WPF app I am trying to load an html file(from inside my project, name of html file is index.html) in to a WebBrowser component.

I followed an answer byghostJago from this question: [Load local HTML file in a C# WebBrowser](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7194851/load-local-html-file-in-a-c-sharp-webbrowser) , but the problem is, the directory of the html file I get points to a Debug folder ( E.g *C:\Users\user1\source\repos\AppName\AppName\bin\Debug* ).

The first time I ran my project in debug mode, the html file wasn't in the debug folder, I had to paste it in there. So is it possible to load a html file from within visual studio project at runtime? If so, how do I do it?

Code that points to Debug folder:

```
string curDir = Directory.GetCurrentDirectory();
string myFile = System.IO.Path.Combine(curDir, "index.html");
WebView.Navigate("file:///" + myFile);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have a file listed in Visual Studios solution explorer, you should be able to right click it, select properties and in the properties pane set the **"Copy to Output Directory"** to **"Copy always"**.

The file will then end up next to the exe in the same debug folder and you will be able to refer to it with your existing code.