# Is it possible to use Plotly.js in a C# Winforms WebBrowser component?

Tags: c#, winforms, webbrowser-control, plotly

I am attempting to use Plotly.js in a C# Winforms desktop application from within a WebBrowser toolbox component for the sake of seamlessness, and am having some difficulties. The code is loaded into the component by assigning the literal string to WebBrowser.DocumentText property.

Specifically, I get the following error when the program is run: "Plotly is undefined." The same code, when pasted into a file called index.html, loads and runs correctly in a FireFox browser window when double-clicked. Must be something REALLY simple and newbie or just ignorant.

Here are the contents of the index.html file:

```
<html>
<head>
<script src = 'plotly-latest.min.js'></script>
</head>
<body>
<div id = "myDiv"></div>
<script>
var myDiv = document.getElementById('myDiv');
var trace = {
x : [9,8,5,1],
y : [1,2,4,8],
z : [11,8,15,3],
mode : 'lines' };
var data = [trace];
Plotly.newPlot(myDiv, data);
</script>
</body>
<html>
```

Thanks for any assistance you might render (pun intended!).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

WebBrowser control by default uses IE6 which is not compatible to Plotly.js. You can make it use IE11 to display your graph [using windows registry](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38514446/1311748). You can also [do it in code](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25650219/1311748) if you need to distribute your app.

You also have an option of ditching WebBrowser control and use third party browser controls like CefSharp (free) or DotNetBrowser (commercial).

Comment: Tried the CefSharp component, and it runs correctly (apparently) because I have some alerts in there, but get the same error !! in console message which I trapped. Nice try, though. I'll try the registry method next.

Comment: I tested your code after setting registry values to `00002af9` and it works fine. I did set script src to `https://cdn.plot.ly/plotly-latest.min.js` when testing.

Comment: Tried it again, using your src, and it worked this time. Thanks for your continued patience, matched only by my own perseverence...really WANTED to get this to work!!

Comment: Wonder what the problem is with using a local file...I'm sure that's just another hurdle !!

Comment: You can use `file://` link to load it from local folder. Checkout https://stackoverflow.com/a/7194956/1311748. Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

Maybe too old to answer but I just tried doing it like this and it seems to work for now:

Using the Plotly.NET package, make a chart and then use `chart.SaveHTMLAs<>` and give it a name. Then, with a webBrowser object navigate to that html.

Here is my code:

```
        Plotly.NET.GenericChart.GenericChart point3Dchart =  Plotly.NET.Chart3D.Chart.Point3D<int, int, int, int>(tuppList, "p");
        point3Dchart.SaveHtmlAs<int>("a", null);
        //point3Dchart.Show(); // Will open firefox
        webBrowser1.Navigate(@"C:\...\bin\Debug\a.html");
```

I'm unsure right now why the `SaveHTMLAs` is asking for `<>` but writing `int` seems to work!

Answer (score 0):

The `WebBrowser` .NET component is using Internet Explorer which, as other mention, probably cannot render modern JavaScript used by Plotly.js

For .NET you can use one of the following:

1. the `WebView2` control which uses Edge to render the web page

   [WebView article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/webview2/get-started/winforms)

   [WebView2 component on NuGet](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Web.WebView2)

   `NuGet\Install-Package Microsoft.Web.WebView2`
2. `CefSharp` - a .NET wrapper around the Chromium Embedded Framework (CEF) which uses Chromium engine to render pages (very similar with the engine used by the Chrome browser)

   [CefSharp github repository](https://github.com/cefsharp/CefSharp)

   [CefSharp.WinForms package](https://CefSharp.WinForms)

   `NuGet\Install-Package CefSharp.WinForms`

You can use your solution to make a page with JavaScript and load it in one the above webbrowser control or

you can use [Plotly.NET](https://github.com/plotly/Plotly.NET) to render Plotly directly from C#.
Example:

```
        using Plotly.NET;
        using Plotly.NET.LayoutObjects;
        ...

        LinearAxis xAxis = new LinearAxis();
        xAxis.SetValue("title", "xAxis");
        xAxis.SetValue("showgrid", false);
        xAxis.SetValue("showline", true);

        LinearAxis yAxis = new LinearAxis();
        yAxis.SetValue("title", "yAxis");
        yAxis.SetValue("showgrid", false);
        yAxis.SetValue("showline", true);

        LinearAxis zAxis = new LinearAxis();
        zAxis.SetValue("title", "zAxis");
        zAxis.SetValue("showgrid", false);
        zAxis.SetValue("showline", true);

        Layout layout = new Layout();
        layout.SetValue("xaxis", xAxis);
        layout.SetValue("yaxis", yAxis);
        layout.SetValue("zaxis", zAxis);
        layout.SetValue("showlegend", true);

        List<Tuple<double, double, double>> p = new List<Tuple<double, double, double>>();

        foreach (var m in batch.Measurements)
        {
            var (_x, _y, _z) = m.GetCartesianCoordinates();
            p.Add(Tuple.Create(_x, _y, _z));
        }

        string plotHtmlFilePath = GetNewUniqueTempPath();

        Plotly.NET.Chart3D.Chart.Point3D<double, double, double, double>(p.ToArray())
            .WithLayout(layout)
            .SaveHtml(plotHtmlFilePath);

// using WebView2 control
            plotWebView.Source = new Uri(plotHtmlFilePath);
```

or it can open it for you in the default browser:

```
    Plotly.NET.Chart3D.Chart.Point3D<double, double, double, double>(p.ToArray())
        .WithLayout(layout)                
        .Show();
```