# WPF WebBrowser won't show Google Maps

Tags: c#, wpf, google-maps, webbrowser-control

This is a follow up question to this question:

[Load local HTML file in a C# WebBrowser](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7194851/load-local-html-file-in-a-c-sharp-webbrowser)

I've created an html file by simply copying the example from this link:

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/marker-simple

When I run it by double clicking the file which opens the regular web browser (i.e Firefox), it works. I then added the HTML to my sln, and change the file's property to always be copied to the output directory. I then tried running it like this:

```
string curDir = Directory.GetCurrentDirectory();
webBrowser.Navigate(new Uri(String.Format("file:\\{0}\\mymap.html", curDir)));
```

The browser is opened with the yellow warning on top:

> "to help protect your security, your browser has restricted this file from showing active content .."

I'm clicking it, allowing the blocked content, and then I get a message saying there's an error in the script in the page. I'm allowing it to continue, and the browser remains blank.. why is that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After searching for an answer, I came across this blog entry:

https://weblog.west-wind.com/posts/2011/May/21/Web-Browser-Control-Specifying-the-IE-Version

First of all for the yellow warning, just add this comment line under the `html` tag of the page:

```
<!-- saved from url=(0016)http://localhost -->
```

You can read more about it here:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/internet-explorer/ie-developer/compatibility/ms537628(v=vs.85)

Regarding the map and the script error:

It seems like you need to set the WebBrowser's IE version to edge, in order to be able to render HTML5.

set this line as the first one inside the `head` tag:

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=Edge">
```

After these 2 changes, it will work

Comment: IE=Edge dind't fix the script error