# Why is the Url value in C# WebBrowser always null?

Tags: c#, url, webbrowser-control

I am trying to load a local HTML file into an instance of C# WebBrowser (WinForms).
This is what I am doing:

```
string url  = @"file:///C:MyHtml/hello.html";
myWebbrowser.Url    = new Uri(url, UriKind.Absolute);
object test = myWebbrowser.Url; // breakpoint here
```

The path above is correct; if I copy it and paste into an external browser, the file is immediately opened. But the instance of WebBrowser does not want to react. I set a breakpoint in the last line of the snippet, and what I get there is that `myWebbrowser.Url` is `null` (the `test` variable). The control remains correspondingly empty.

`myWebbrowser.AllowNavigation`  is explicitly set to `true`. I have also tried all possible versions of slashes and backslashes; the result is always the same. The version of the webbrowser seems to be 11 (`myWebbrowser.Version` = "{11.0.18362.1139}"). I am working in Windows 10, VS 2019.

What can be wrong in this setup?

Comment: The format is `new Uri(String.Format("file:///{0}/hello.html", Directory.GetCurrentDirectory()));` *or* `new Uri(String.Format(pathtofile, directoryfileisin));`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Load local HTML file in a C# WebBrowser](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7194851/load-local-html-file-in-a-c-sharp-webbrowser)

Comment: @Çöđěxěŕ Don't be surprised: I have just typed my comment in Francesca's computer, we are looking together.

Comment: @Çöđěxěŕ Thanks for your tips, but is still does not work. The Url value is still null. BTW, your second version does not contain a {0} and therefore seems to me to be less reasonable. The link you mention contains principally the same tricks you suggest, I looked at them hours ago...

Answer (score 2):

> The path above is correct; if I copy it and paste into an external browser, the file is immediately opened. But the instance of WebBrowser does not want to react. I set a breakpoint in the last line of the snippet, and what I get there is that myWebbrowser.Url is `null`.

I was able to replicate this exact issue, it's because the property of the `Url` doesn't get actually set until the document has actually finished loading.

To resolve this issue, you must handle the `DocumentCompleted` event. You can do so for example:

```
 string url  = @"file:///C:MyHtml/hello.html";
 myWebbrowser.DocumentCompleted += MyWebbrowser_DocumentCompleted;
 myWebbrowser.Url = new Uri(url, UriKind.Absolute);
```

Create a new routine to handle the `DocumentCompleted` event:

```
 private void MyWebbrowser_DocumentCompleted(object sender, WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventArgs e)
 {
    string test = myWebbrowser.Url.ToString();
 }
```

You can also get the `Url` from the `WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventArgs`:

```
 string testUrl = e.Url.ToString();
```

I am not sure exactly why when setting the `Url` and then checking it, it is `null`, I haven't found anything to explain why. My only guess is that it may be an invalid `Url` and or path, if navigation succeeds then that property is set.

*Edit*: upon looking at the source for `WebBrowserDocumentCompleted`, it does seem the `Url` property is only set in the `DocumentCompleted`, you can [see](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Windows.Forms/winforms/Managed/System/WinForms/WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventHandler.cs,5b23629a32001c59) more there.

---

**Please note**: you must register the `DocumentCompleted` event first before setting the `Url` property as when you do, it will navigate first and you will not receive the `DocumentCompleted` event.

Comment: DocumentCompleted can be a fruitful idea, I will test it right now. But I still do not uinderstand why it all functions if I take the URL string as "`http://www.google.com`" ?

Comment: After DocumentCompleted handler has worked the Url in the browser is really no longer null, but the control itself remains empty. This is what it is:

Answer (score 1):

I was able to find out why it did not want to function, at least I hope so. The "hello.html" file contained calls to jquery and THREE.js, while WebBroser seems not to support the latter. Therefore I did not see any content in the control. After I threw out THREE.js and inserted most simple HTML code, it worked just OK! Now I am busy trying to bring WebBrowser to support THREE.js (there exists a skeptical opinion about this, though).